# Meteor subscription method doesn't work after page reloading

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, iron-router

I have an Iron Router route where in `waitOn` I subscribe to a publication.
If I load my main page first and then click the link that references that route everything is fine. But if I reload the page the subscription doesn't work: it returns an empty collection.

```
Router.route('/profileEdit/:_id',
  {    
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('getUser');
    },
    data: function () {
      let user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.params._id});     
      if (!user) {
        throw new Error('user undefined');
      }
      let profile = {
        'profile.firstName': user.profile.firstName,
        'profile.lastName': user.profile.lastName,
         email: user.emails[0].address,
        'profile.age':user.profile.age,
        'profile.gender':user.profile.gender,
        'profile.aboutMe':user.profile.aboutMe,
      }
      return profile;
    },
    name: 'profileEdit'
  }
);
```

Comment: You should your publication method as well

Comment: Shouldn't `this.params._id` be a parameter to your subscription? You're trying to retrieve a single user document correct? How does the publication know which one to send?